# Accessing argparse arguments from the class

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x

I have the following sample code running unit tests:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import unittest
import argparse

class ParentTest(unittest.TestCase):
    None

class Test1(ParentTest):
    def test_if_verbose(self):
        import __main__ # FIXME
        print("Success!") if __main__.args.verbose else "" # FIXME

class Test2(ParentTest):
    None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Parse arguments.
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
    parser.add_argument("-?", "--help",     action="help",                        help="show this help message and exit" )
    parser.add_argument("-v", "--verbose",  action="store_true", dest="verbose",  help="increase output verbosity" )
    parser.add_argument('files', nargs='*')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    print(args.verbose)

    # Add tests.
    alltests = unittest.TestSuite()
    alltests.addTest(unittest.makeSuite(Test1))
    alltests.addTest(unittest.makeSuite(Test2))

    result = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(alltests) # Run tests.
    sys.exit(not result.wasSuccessful())
```

and I'd like to access command-line argument values from the class.

In [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3648387/55075) it's suggested that using `__main__` isn't really a good approach.

Is there any better way of doing it, where individual tests could have access to argument values which were parsed already in `main`?

Testing:

```
python3 test.py
python3 test.py -v
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this by making the test classes take args as parameter, and crafting a custom `make_suite` method instead of `unittest.makeSuite`, like this:

```
class ParentTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def __init__(self, methodName='runTest', args=None):
        super().__init__(methodName)
        self.args = args

class Test1(ParentTest):
    def test_if_verbose(self):
        print("Success!") if self.args.verbose else ""

class Test2(ParentTest):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
    parser.add_argument("-?", "--help",     action="help",                        help="show this help message and exit" )
    parser.add_argument("-v", "--verbose",  action="store_true", dest="verbose",  help="increase output verbosity" )
    parser.add_argument('files', nargs='*')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    print(args.verbose)

    def make_suite(testcase_class):
        testloader = unittest.TestLoader()
        testnames = testloader.getTestCaseNames(testcase_class)
        suite = unittest.TestSuite()
        for name in testnames:
            suite.addTest(testcase_class(name, args=args))
        return suite

    # Add tests.
    alltests = unittest.TestSuite()
    alltests.addTest(make_suite(Test1))
    alltests.addTest(make_suite(Test2))

    result = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(alltests) # Run tests.
    sys.exit(not result.wasSuccessful())
```

The sample output is the same as the original code:

> ```
> $ python t2.py ; python t2.py -v
> False
> test_if_verbose (__main__.Test1) ... ok
>
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
> Ran 1 test in 0.000s
>
> OK
> True
> test_if_verbose (__main__.Test1) ... Success!
> ok
>
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
> Ran 1 test in 0.000s
>
> OK
> ```

The code in my answer was inspired by these posts:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/17260551/641955
- http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/08/02/python-unit-testing-parametrized-test-cases/

Comment: `super()__init__` should be `super(ParentTest,self)__init__`? apart from this, this is a great example

Answer (score 1):

Why not just access `args` directly as a global variable, instead of through `__main__`? If this is all just a single file -- which means it is one module called `__main__` -- then you don't need to import anything. Instead of this:

```
def test_if_verbose(self):
    import __main__ # FIXME
    print("Success!") if __main__.args.verbose else "" # FIXME
```

Just do this:

```
def test_if_verbose(self):
    print("Success!") if args.verbose else ""
```

Of course, that will only work as long as you don't split the code into modules. janos's solution looks cleaner and doesn't have that restriction -- I just wanted to point out that in this particular case, technically, a simpler way exists.